# Using containsLocation with a google.maps.Data.polygon

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have a google.maps.Data layer with a polygon feature:

```
state = new google.maps.Data();
state.loadGeoJson('static/geojson/ga_state.geojson', {
    idPropertyName: 'name'
});
state.setStyle({
    clickable: false,
    visible: false,
});
state.setMap(map);
```

Within this feature collection is a polygon representing the state of Georgia:

```
ga = state.getFeatureById('Georgia')
```

I can get the geometry of this feature:

```
gaGeom = ga.getGeometry()
```

But when I pass either of these objects and also the raw array to google.maps.geometry.polygon.containsFeature(), I get an error that the object does not contain the get() fuction:

```
google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(p.getPosition(), ga)
Uncaught TypeError: b.get is not a function(…)

google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(p.getPosition(), gaGeom)
Uncaught TypeError: b.get is not a function(…)

google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(p.getPosition(), gaGeom.getArray())
Uncaught TypeError: b.get is not a function(…)
```

How can I get a google.maps.Data.Polygon to either convert to a google.maps.Polygon or to work with this function?

**EDIT:**

I have found a way to construct a google.maps.Polygon from a google.maps.Data.Polygon as:

```
//gaGeom is the feature.geometry from the data layer
poly = new google.maps.Polygon({paths:gaGeom.getAt(0).getArray()})
```

But surely there has to be a cleaner way to construct the google.maps.Polygon?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The [google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation method](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#poly) takes a point (a [google.maps.LatLng](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#LatLng)) and a polygon (a [google.maps.Polygon](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#Polygon)).

> containsLocation(point:LatLng, polygon:Polygon)
>   Return Value:  boolean
>   Computes whether the given point lies inside the specified polygon.

- `ga = state.getFeatureById('Georgia')`  returns a ["feature"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.Feature)
- `gaGeom = ga.getGeometry()` returns a ["Geometry"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.Geometry)
- `gaGeom.getArray()` returns an ["Array"](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/3.exp/reference#Data.LinearRing) of LinearRings

None of which is a google.maps.Polygon.  You can make a google.maps.Polygon from the Array (as I see you have discovered while I wrote this).

[proof of concept](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_GeoJSON_test.html)

**code:**

```
function initialize() {
  var map = new google.maps.Map(
    document.getElementById("map_canvas"), {
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(37.4419, -122.1419),
      zoom: 13,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
  var state = new google.maps.Data();
  var poly;
  state.addListener('addfeature', function(evt) {
    if (evt.feature.getId() == "Georgia") {
      var ga = state.getFeatureById('Georgia');
      var gaGeom = ga.getGeometry();
      //gaGeom is the feature.geometry from the data layer
      poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: gaGeom.getAt(0).getArray(),
        map: map,
        clickable: false
      });
    }
  });
  var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
  google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(evt) {
    infoWindow.setPosition(evt.latLng);
    if (google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(evt.latLng, poly)) {
      infoWindow.setContent("INSIDE POLY<br>" + evt.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
    } else {
      infoWindow.setContent("OUTSIDE POLY<br>" + evt.latLng.toUrlValue(6));
    }
    infoWindow.open(map);
  });

  state.loadGeoJson("http://www.geocodezip.com/GeoJSON/gz_2010_us_040_00_500k.json.txt", {
    idPropertyName: 'NAME'
  });
  state.setStyle({
    clickable: false,
    visible: false,
  });
  state.setMap(map);

  var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  geocoder.geocode({
    'address': "State of Georgia"
  }, function(results, status) {
    if (status === google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      map.fitBounds(results[0].geometry.viewport);
    } else {
      alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
    }
  });
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, "load", initialize);
```