# Google Maps API: Want geolocation to click automatically on data layer below

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am trying to build a map-based site that identifies a user's geolocation, draws a marker at his/her position, and then uses that marker/location to click on a data layer (in this case, a GeoJSON layer). Essentially, the user's location should trigger an infowindow automatically if he or she is located on an area delineated by the geojson file. Ideally, each time the user changes location it will be clicking the map to check this GeoJSON layer for info.

So far, I can get the user's location successfully. The map centers on that location. And manual clicks on the GeoJSON layer also populate the info window correctly. But it's not clicking automatically when getting the user location.

I've seen lots of examples where a forced click on a marker takes place, but I can't seem to find one that clicks a data layer. Unfortunately I'm more of a GIS person assigned to a coding job on this, which is way out of my league, so I'm struggling to figure out where I'm going wrong with this.

Here's the script, perhaps I'm making a mistake here:

```
$<script type="text/javascript">

    //centers the map on Iowa City
        var map,
            currentPositionMarker,
            mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.661354, -91.534729),
            map;

        function initializeMap()
        {
            map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
               zoom: 18,
               center: mapCenter,
               mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
             });

            map.data.loadGeoJson('test2.json');
            map.data.setStyle({
            strokeColor: '#2687bf',
            strokeWeight: 5
            });

             map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
            document.getElementById('info-box').textContent =
            event.feature.getProperty('description');
        });

        }

        function locError(error) {
            // the current position could not be located
            alert("The current position could not be found!");
        }

        function setCurrentPosition(pos) {
            currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                draggable: true,
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(
                    pos.coords.latitude,
                    pos.coords.longitude
                ),
                title: "Current Position"
            });
            new google.maps.event.trigger( 'test2.json', 'click' );

            map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
                    pos.coords.latitude,
                    pos.coords.longitude
                ));

        }

        function displayAndWatch(position) {
            // set current position
            setCurrentPosition(position);
            // watch position
            watchCurrentPosition();
        }

        function watchCurrentPosition() {
            var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(
                function (position) {
                    setMarkerPosition(
                        currentPositionMarker,
                        position
                    );
                });
        }

        function setMarkerPosition(marker, position) {
            marker.setPosition(
                new google.maps.LatLng(
                    position.coords.latitude,
                    position.coords.longitude)
            );
        }

        function initLocationProcedure() {
            initializeMap();
            if (navigator.geolocation) {
                navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayAndWatch, locError);
            } else {
                alert("Your browser does not support the Geolocation API");
            }
        }

        $(document).ready(function() {
            initLocationProcedure();
        });

    </script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="map_canvas" style="height:600px;"></div>
     <div id="info-box" style="height:250px;">INFO</div>

</body>

</html>
```

And here are links to my JSON and full HTML file for this: 
https://sites.google.com/site/ecocritkml/coding

The JSON is obviously specific to Iowa City, Iowa, but it could be modified easily in a text editor. Any ideas would be really helpful here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I got it.

I had to use a few tricks (some maybe a little dirty)

- I put a 500ms delay with setTimeout; this could have been done more elegantly, no doubt
- I make a temporary polygon, because it permits to use containsLocation()
- I don't invoke a click, but there is a loop over the polygon features, I read the description there, and set it to the div

..

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
      <title>Google maps</title>
      <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
      <script type="text/javascript" src=http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3&sensor=true&language=en"></script>
  <style>
      html, body {
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
      }
      #map_canvas {
        height: 100%;
      }
      #info-box {
        background-color: white;
        border: 1px solid black;
        bottom: 30px;
        height: 20px;
        padding: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 30px;
      }
    </style>

<script type="text/javascript">


    //centers the map on Iowa City
    var map,
        currentPositionMarker,
        mapCenter = new google.maps.LatLng(41.661354, -91.534729),
        map;

    function initializeMap() {
      map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), {
        zoom: 18,
        center: mapCenter,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
      });
      map.data.loadGeoJson('test2.json');
      map.data.setStyle({
        strokeColor: '#2687bf',
        strokeWeight: 5
      });
      map.data.addListener('click', function(event) {
        document.getElementById('info-box').textContent = event.feature.getProperty('description');
      });

    }
    function locError(error) {
        // the current position could not be located
    }
    function setCurrentPosition(pos) {

      currentPositionMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        map: map,
        draggable: true,
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(
          pos.coords.latitude,
          pos.coords.longitude
        ),
        title: "Current Position"
      });

      // Wait half a second, then take a loop of the features, see if the marker is inside one of them
      setTimeout(function() {
        map.data.forEach(function(feature){
          var figure = feature.getGeometry();
          if(figure.getType() == 'Polygon') {

            // make a temporary polygon, see if the marker is inside
            var tempPolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
              paths: figure.getAt(0).getArray(),  // @see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33249127/using-containslocation-with-a-google-maps-data-polygon
              map: null
            });

            if(google.maps.geometry.poly.containsLocation(currentPositionMarker.getPosition(), tempPolygon)) {
              // marker is inside this feature
              // invoke a click. well, just pretend  ...
              document.getElementById('info-box').textContent = feature.getProperty('description');
            }
          }
          var b;
        }) 
      }, 500);

      map.panTo(new google.maps.LatLng(
        pos.coords.latitude,
        pos.coords.longitude
      ));
    }
    function displayAndWatch(position) {
        // set current position
         setCurrentPosition(position);
        // watch position
        watchCurrentPosition();
    }
    function watchCurrentPosition() {
      var positionTimer = navigator.geolocation.watchPosition(function (position) {
        setMarkerPosition(
          currentPositionMarker,
          position
        );
      });
    }
    function setMarkerPosition(marker, position) {
        marker.setPosition(
          new google.maps.LatLng(
            position.coords.latitude,
            position.coords.longitude
          )
        );
        // now we see if the marker is inside one of the polygons
        var a = 0;
    }
    function initLocationProcedure() {
      initializeMap();
      if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(displayAndWatch, locError);

      } 
      else {
        // alert("Your browser does not support the Geolocation API");
      }
    }
    $(document).ready(function() {
        initLocationProcedure();
    });
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="map_canvas" style="height:600px;"></div>
     <div id="info-box" style="height:250px;">INFO</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Yes. Thank you so much! This appears to work fairly well. I tested it out in the field on my cell phone and although was a little hit or miss at times, I don't think that's a problem with the code. Just the fact that it was working properly at all was enough for me.

Hey, dirty or not, this will help me immensely. I really appreciate your time.